# invalid character constant in var

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, kml

Im trying to load KML file into my app with [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/#initializing_the_map) tutorial
and I'm getting invalid character constant error at this line

```
var src = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/westcampus.kml';
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: For starters, that's not Java. And in Java, you'd use a String constant with `"` instead of `'`. Maybe the tutorial you're following is for integration on a website with javascript?

Comment: @323g do you know how to do it in java?

Comment: Sure, but why don't you use google to find a tutorial? There are lots of them out there.

Comment: already search it, but cant apply on my app, just above tutorial is easy enough for me to understand

Comment: Keep searching. The above tutorial won't help you, because it doesn't actually show you what *you* need to do in an Android app. It's like reading a recipe for meatloaf and then trying to drive a car. They are different categories. Regardless, this is not the forum to ask for tutorials -- in fact, those questions are strictly off-topic.

Comment: thank you sir for your answer, Im too new for this

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the syntax for a String is:

```
String src = "https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/westcampus.kml";
```

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

That tutorial is in JavaScript, not Java.

Comment: While this is correct, this is not going to help the OP convert a JavaScript tutorial to an Android project. That is the real issue here.

Comment: Probably because the tutorial is in a different language. @AlohaSiere

Comment: Well she didn't ask for us to convert a whole tutorial to Java, just how to fix that one line. Sorry but I can't infer that from the question @dharms